# unable to parse dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

when am trying to fetch the data from the dictionary am getting this error Value of tuple type 'NSDictionary.Element' (aka '(key: Any, value: Any)') has no member 'subscript'.

```
var productDictionary : NSDictionary? 

 @objc func ButtonClick(sender : UIButton)
{
 let buttonPostion = (sender as AnyObject).convert((sender as AnyObject).bounds.origin, to: self.TableviewFirst)
      if let indexPath = self.TableviewFirst.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPostion) {
            let datarrayval = shopList[indexPath.row]
            for (index, element) in productDictionary!.enumerated()
            {
                print("element",element)

               let iteminner = element as? Dictionary<String, Any> ------> I am trying to fetch 

            }
        }
    }

this is the response for element 
element (key: products, value: <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6000009a8ed0>(
{
    aprice = "150.00";
    "c_id" = 5;
    "created_at" = "2019-10-23 11:51:46";
    discount = "34.00";
    gdescription = "Foxtail Millets";
    id = 5;
    image = "3118e9d253daabf4186f5df25af6d26e.jpg";
    "m_id" = 5;
    pcode = KP00005;
    price = "99.00";
    "product_qty" = 0;
    qty = "500 G";
    "s_id" = 7;
    status = active;
    "stock_id" = 1;
    stockqty = 50;
    title = "Foxtile Millets";
}
)
)
```

when I tried fetch the data from the above values

Answer (score 0):

For `Dictionary` objects, `enumerated` returns a an array of tuples of type

```
(Int, (key: Any, value: Any))
```

(Nested tuples, in other words)

So in your code, `element` will contain a tuple of type `(key: String, value: Any)`. You can't cast a tuple to a dictionary, so that code fails.